# conditional sum in select statement

Tags: sql-server

I’m trying to do conditional sum in select statement a table but I can’t think of way to do so.

The sum should keep on going until it hits a reset flag in the table.

Increment values need to be set to 0 when reset flag is hit(1) and it should start summing again from next row.

Please have a look at the data structure I want to select from my a big table

```
ID  Value  ValueIncrement                   ResetFlag
1     2          2                              0   
2     3          5  (2+3)                       0
3     9          14 (2+3+9)                     0   
4     6          20 (2+3+9+6)                   0
5     3          23 (2+3+9+6+3)                 0
6     1          24 (2+3+9+6+3+1)               0
7     2          26 (2+3+9+6+3+1+2)             0
8     0          26 (2+3+9+6+3+1+2+0)           0
9     2          30 (2+3+9+6+3+1+2+0+2)         1
10    4          4                              0   
11    5          9 (4+5)                        0
12    3          12 (4+5+3)                     0   
13    6          18 (4+5+3+6)                   0
14    7          25(4+5+3+6+7)                  0
15    4          29(4+5+3+6+7+4)                0
16    7          36(4+5+3+6+7+4+7)              0
17    9          ‭45‬(4+5+3+6+7+4+7+9)          0   
18    2          47(4+5+3+6+7+4+7+9+2)          0
19    1          48(4+5+3+6+7+4+7+9+2+1)        0
20    1          49(4+5+3+6+7+4+7+9+2+1+1)      1
```

I tried few things but I couldn’t get it to work the way I need, any help or suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: You say you've tried, what didnt work about it? What was your atte.pt? (Show your code.) This doesn't look like a conditional `SUM` but a cumulative `SUM`.

Comment: I have tried SUM(Col1) Over (order by id) AS OutPut in select but it runs through the entire dataset which isnt what i need, Im trying to dissect chunks of dataset when reset flag is hit so it start summing all over again for a next chuck. I have created while loops and temporary tables but i didnt put all the code just  to keep things simple.

Comment: Please, can you confirm the values in the expected result (rows 17, 18, 19, 20)? Thanks.

Comment: ZhorovThe values have been corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution, using window functions:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
    ID int,  
    [Value] int,
    ResetFlag int,
)
INSERT INTO Data 
    (ID, [Value], ResetFlag)
VALUES
    (1 , 2, 0),   
    (2 , 3, 0),
    (3 , 9, 0),   
    (4 , 6, 0),
    (5 , 3, 0),
    (6 , 1, 0),
    (7 , 2, 0),
    (8 , 0, 0),
    (9 , 2, 1),
    (10, 4, 0),   
    (11, 5, 0),
    (12, 3, 0),   
    (13, 6, 0),
    (14, 7, 0),
    (15, 4, 0),
    (16, 7, 0),
    (17, 9, 0),   
    (18, 2, 0),
    (19, 1, 0),
    (20, 1, 1)
```

Statement:

```
;WITH GroupsCTE AS (
    SELECT 
        ID, [Value], ResetFlag,
        CASE WHEN LAG(ResetFlag) OVER (ORDER BY ID) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NewGroup
    FROM Data
), FinalCTE AS (
    SELECT 
        ID, [Value], ResetFlag,
        SUM(NewGroup) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS GroupID
    FROM GroupsCTE
)
SELECT 
    ID, [Value], ResetFlag, SUM([Value]) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupID ORDER BY ID) AS ValueIncrement
FROM FinalCTE
```

Result:

```
--------------------------------------
ID  Value   ResetFlag   ValueIncrement
--------------------------------------
1   2       0           2
2   3       0           5
3   9       0           14
4   6       0           20
5   3       0           23
6   1       0           24
7   2       0           26
8   0       0           26
9   2       1           28
10  4       0           4
11  5       0           9
12  3       0           12
13  6       0           18
14  7       0           25
15  4       0           29
16  7       0           36
17  9       0           45
18  2       0           47
19  1       0           48
20  1       1           49
```

Comment: Zhorov, Thanks for the help, the table partitioning has worked well and it does dissect the dataset really well and sum it up as it goes along. Once more thanks for your time and effort.